# Variable has incomplete type 'class __declspec'

Tags: c++, objective-c++

I'm writing in Objective-C++ and one of my .mm files imports a cpp header with a class that implements abstract class.
Abstract class looks like this:

```
class __declspec(novtable) IBase
{
public:
    virtual ~IBase() {}
};
```

While compiling the sources I get this error:

```
error: variable has incomplete type 'class __declspec'
```

What is the reason of this error?

UPD: It's worth to mention that I'm dealing with a crossplatform code that I'm refactoring.

UPD1: Defining on a top of .mm

```
#define __declspec
```

didn't help.

Comment: `__declspec` is a MSVC extension does Objective-C++ understand this ?

Comment: There are probably no Microsoft-specific extensions in Objective C++.

Comment: Alghouth several of hte __declspec and related are supported by GCC and Clang. Probably not in Objective C++ mode tho'.

Comment: Indeed - clang on OSX does not know about the __declspec.

Comment: It is the kind of code that is common when writing COM code.  It declares an interface, novtable tells the compiler to not generate the C++ class runtime overhead.  Not necessary because an interface always needs to be implemented by a concrete class.  COM is very strongly tied to Windows, the odds that this can come to a good end on an Apple OS are pretty low.  First basic obstacle is that your compiler does not understand what the declspec means.  Only the first.